# Name for this percussion instrument?

Tags: music

What is the name of this percussion instrument in English?

It is gripped by the round handle. By using circular movements of the hand, the flat part is spun around the handle, causing the thin wooden leaf in the middle to snap against the gear and emit a repeating sharp sound.

[image: mystery instrument]

Comment: Do you know the name of it in a different language? If you look it up on Wikipedia in your native language, you can look at the language options in the sidebar to see if there's a "view this page in English" link. That's how I translate a lot of unique stuff.

Comment: It's a [*ratchet*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratchet_(instrument)).

Comment: Otherwuse known as  a **Football Rattle**  www.amazon.co.uk/Football-Rattle -

Comment: It "is", as it were, a ratchet - but it's usually just called a "rattle".  (Although it's nothing like a rattle.)  But then, people are staggeringly stupid - what are you gonne do?

Comment: @Catija there is no interwiki link in this case.

Comment: @stoneyb Oh. And here I thought it was just called simply a 'noise maker'.

Comment: @mitch We percussionists have a lot of noisemakers, but they all have different names so we know what kind of noise to make when.

Comment: @StoneyB for me they all go bang

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your description I had to think - same as **StoneyB** commented** - of an

**Ratchet**

They are often used at sports events.

---

** and in the minute of this post also Hugh did

Answer (score 1):

'Ratchet' is clearly the American word, and is the Wikipedia entry. (+1 @Daniel)

So, purely for completeness:
'Football Rattle' is usual in Br English, even though many Clubs have banned its use. There are also two manufacturers making them for percussion instruments, *qua* ratchets, clackers, rattles and even football rattles.

http://www.knotjustjigs.co.uk/football-rattle-football-clacker-286-p.asp

http://www.americanbell.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=4341

http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sport/football/article-2464574/New-Anfield-exhibit-seen-treasures-Liverpools-history.html

http://www.jampercussion.com/buy/percussion-plus-football-rattle_687.htm