# What is the name of this keyboard music instrument?

Tags: single-word-requests, music

I see a piano-like instrument on many of the fifties and sixties music videos.  One of the best ways to describe is to show it to you:

[image]

[Source: [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0sB3Fjw3Uvc)]

The Doors keyboard man also played it. It has a special sound and surely its name is not just 'Piano'.

What is ITS name?

Comment: I don't think this is on-topic for this site, but you may generically refer to any musical instrument with a piano-like keyboard as a *[keyboard instrument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_instrument)*, or in context, simply a *keyboard*. It is probably either an *electric piano* or a *synthesizer*.

Comment: Well, there's always *synthesizer*, as @choster suggests.  And the mother of all synthesizers was the [Moog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moog_synthesizer), though they were generally more sophisticated than the one pictured in the video.

Comment: Probably the [Music Stack Exchange site](http://music.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to pursue this.

Comment: The relevant [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_House_of_the_Rising_Sun) mentions *Alan Price's pulsating **organ** part (played on a **Vox Continental**)*. My apologies to anyone offended by the collocation *pulsating organ* - not my words, I just cut&pasted.

Comment: Actually, music.SE doesn't do instrument identification questions. But this isn't a question about English (or even musical terms in English) either.

Comment: This question would be welcome on the [Music Fans Stack Exchange site](http://musicfans.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @AndrewLeach It most certainly is a question about English vocabulary, in particular a request for a particular noun.  There's even the appropriate tag given, under which you can find this perfectly acceptable and accepted question: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/253157/name-for-this-percussion-instrument

Comment: There is a difference between asking what the name of an object is (which may or may not be musical), and identifying a particular musical instrument.  Even if a question might be on-topic on a particular site, there could well be a different site it's more on-topic on, and it's correct to migrate it there. That does appear to be Music Fans in this case, a site I wasn't aware of.

Comment: The Doors keyboard man?  You mean Ray Mazerak?

Comment: You're right that this isn't simply an organ or keyboard or synth.  People referred to it is the Vox or the Continental.  Manzerak also had a Rhodes and a bass pedal that he used on Riders on the Storm.  That Vox defined their sound, and was used by other bands.

Comment: Btw, Andrew is right in closing this question.  Vox Continental isn't the same kind of word that piano is, and even a piano question isn't on topic.  Don't take it personally...just the "style" around here.  I've had questions closed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The instrument is a Vox Continental combo organ, a popular instrument for bands that toured.

[image]

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vox_Continental):

> The Vox Continental is a transistor-based combo organ that was introduced in 1962. Known for its bright but thin, breathy sound, the "Connie", as it was affectionately known, was designed to be used by touring musicians. It was also designed to replace heavy tonewheel organs, such as the revered Hammond B3.

Comment: Correct. And if the OP was looking for a more broad term, it is an "electric organ" or "electric keyboard."

Comment: thank you  for this answer. I say it because I believe the instrument is not  called simply a keyboard or piano. If not, an old man who lived here wouldn't tell me ' I miss the old .... sound of https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cJEL6b9Z78w'. Apologizes for my english

Comment: Most definitely, by today's definition, @Kyle, though back then they weren't referred to as piano keyboards as much as what they were, which were organs with transistor-based synthesizer capabilities.  I wasn't familiar with the "Connie" but the "Hammond" organ was never referred to as just a piano keyboard and as the Wikipedia article states, it was plain old *revered*! :-)

Comment: @KristinaLopez I edited my post to account for your point. (I added "electric organ.")

Comment: thank you  very much Kristina for the answer and @Kyle for the edit. Perfect

Comment: I did the homework and the result is exacly yours. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kO1_M9jsgA4.

Answer (score 1):

It's normally referred to as simply "the keyboard."

However, *synthesizer*, or *synth*, are also in use, I believe. The separate keyboard part (made by StudioLogic, Korg, Casio, etc) is called "***the keyboard controller***."

[image]